# Android: show notifications when app is closed

Tags: java, android

I have my code on notification in on Create method, but I want to show notification even when app is closed. For example like Messenger has, when u connect to wifi and even and even don't open Messenger notifications are coming.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_photo_or_upload);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Image");
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
    query.whereEqualTo("recipientUsername", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> images, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null) {

                if (images.size() > 0) {

                    for (final ParseObject image : images) {

                        ParseFile file = image.getParseFile("image");
                        byte[] byteArray = new byte[0];
                        try {
                            byteArray = file.getData();
                            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
                        } catch (ParseException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 1, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewPhotos.class), 0);
                        Resources r = getResources();
                        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                                .setLargeIcon(bitmap)
                                .setTicker("You have new photo incoming!")
                                //.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logopt)
                                .setContentTitle("PhotoTSFun")
                                .setContentText(image.getString("sendUsername") + " has sent you an image")
                                .setContentIntent(pi)
                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                .build();

                        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

                    }

                }
            }
        }
    });
```

}

Thanks.

Comment: Implement the code in a service and keep the service running continuously in the background.

Answer (score 0):

1) You must **detect** when your app closing
  a) in activity on destroy or onstop method
  b) onterminate in application class.

2) Send from there intent to **service**

3) In service at onstartcommand/onhandleintent 
put code with **publishing** notification.